# Json.NET serialization pre and post calls

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I am using Json.NET to serialize an object graph. For each object that is serialized or deserialized, I want to call a method on that object before the serialization takes place. For e.g. all my objects implement an interface INotified with a method OnSerializing. I want OnSerializing to be called before the object is serialized.

Is there a way to achieve this without having to touch the Json.NET source code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest version of [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) supports [serialization callbacks](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationCallbacks.html).