# Custom code before and after every tree node serialization in Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to serialize a binary tree using Json.Net:

```
class Node
{
    Node Left;
    Node Right;
    int Data;
}
```

I'd like to add custom code before and after every `Node` serialization, so I've tried using a custom `JsonConverter`:

```
class NodeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Node);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before");
        serializer.serialize(writer, value); // Oops
        Console.WriteLine("After");
    }   
}
```

But this doesn't work because the `JsonSerializer` will endlessly call the `NodeConverter.WriteJson(..)` method.

Can this be done in Json.NET?

Edit:
This is how I'm using the custom converter:

```
var root = CreateTree(); 
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ms))
{
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create();
    serializer.Converters.Add(new NodeConverter());
    serializer.serialize(writer, root);
}
```

Comment: Which custom node?. Could you please add more details to understand your scenario correctly

Comment: @er-sho custom code, not node (for simplicity, I'd like to print "Before" and "After" before and after every node serialization).

Comment: Show me how you use this converter?

Comment: @er-sho Sure, edited the question

Comment: Can you modify the `Node` type to add serialization callbacks?  If so see [Json.NET serialization pre and post calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1048311).

Answer (score 0):

In order to break the loop you can serialize the properties in the `WriteJson` method directly, e.g.:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before");
    var n = (Node)value;
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    SerializeReferencedNode(writer, serializer, "Left", n.Left);
    SerializeReferencedNode(writer, serializer, "Right", n.Right);
    writer.WritePropertyName("Value");
    writer.WriteValue(n.Data);
    writer.WriteEndObject();
    Console.WriteLine("After");
}

private static void SerializeReferencedNode(JsonWriter writer, JsonSerializer serializer, 
                                            string propName, Node node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName(propName);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, node);
    }
}
```

This leads for a simple sample to the following output:

```
{"Left":{"Value":123},"Right":{"Value":246},"Value":0}
```